# XTickLabel with variable intervals at barplot

Tags: matlab, plot, label, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I have a barplot where the bars are located at the following x-coordinates:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,70,80,90
```

I want to show these values at the `XTickLabel`, however when I use

```
figure(1);

Vector = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 35 40 45 50 60 70 80 90]
bar(Vector,Vector);
xticklabels(Vector);
```

I get the following output, but I want that my `XTickLabel` to look like `Vector` at the corresponding values:
[image]

As you can see the `XTickLabel` only goes to 12 and some bars are not labeled.

I tried to use

```
set(gca,'Xtick',1:1:Vector(length(Vector)))
```

But this uses a linear interval for the `Xtick`.

Comment: `set(gca,'Xtick',Vector)`. Don't need the `xticklabel`, it's only when you want other ticks then the values are. and you can't call it as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Adiel had mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507288/xticklabel-with-variable-intervalls-at-barplot/40509451#comment68257122_40507288), use:

```
set(gca,'Xtick', Vector);
```

You don't need `xticklabel`, unless you want ticks label texts that are different from the values at their positions.