# Evenly distribute bar groups in a bar graph with a non-periodic X-Label in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure, figure

I have a Matrix I like to put in a bar chart. This works, however the x-axis is not periodic, it follows the following numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 70 80 90
```

These values are stored in the variable `Batchsizes`, the Matrix is stored in the variable `valuable`

I use the following code:

```
figure;
bar(Batchsizes,valuable);
set(gca,'Xtick',Batchsizes(1:length(Batchsizes)));
```

The following output is generated:

[image]

As you can see, the graph is crowded on the left and wide on the right. I would like to have the bar groups evenly distributed over the x-axis so that the graph is evenly spaced while preserving the old x-labels.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but are you not looking for the opposit: `bar(1:length(Batchsizes),valuable);` and then `set(gca,'Xtick',Batchsizes);`. Ho and by the way: `Batchsizes(1:length(Batchsizes)) == Batchsizes`

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but no not exactly. If I do it this way then the bar groups are evenly distributed but the xlabel is spread (e.g eleven has no number but should have the 12, instead the next one has 12, thus the xlabel only goes to 28, but it shall go to 90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509451/3372061)? This is exactly the case when you *do* want to use `XTickLabel` (because now the ticks will be positioned at `1:1:29` but you want labels to have the values `Batchsizes(1),Batchsizes(2),...`). Here's one way to do it:

```
Batchsizes = [1:9, 10:2:28 30:5:55 60:10:90];
valuable = randi(35,numel(Batchsizes),3);
figure; bar(1:numel(Batchsizes),valuable);
set(gca,'XTick',1:numel(Batchsizes),...
        'XTickLabel',cellstr(num2str(Batchsizes.')));
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you , is there a specific reason for using numel instead of length?

Comment: @Kev1n91 - There's no difference in the case of **vectors** - it's just a habit of mine from working with matrices. `length` works like `max(size(A))`, whereas `numel` is like `prod(size(A))`. Actually, I would always advocate using `size` instead of `length` as results are more predictable this way. P.S. `numel` requires the least amount of characters :)