# How to custom Xtick for bar plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I have used bar plotting (grouped style), as shown in the figure below using this my code.

```
y = [200 200 200 192 160 128 96 64 48 32 96 64 24 48 32;
     48 64 96 48 32 24 24 64 16 24 48 32 48 64 24;
     6 6 2 4 4 6 12 8 2 4 8 6 16 12 6;
   ];
[rows,cols] = size(y);
n = NaN(rows,cols);
c = {'r' 'g' 'b'};
bh = cell(rows,1);
lh = cell(rows,1);

hold on;
for k = 1:rows
    curr = n;
    curr(k,:) = y(k,:);
    bar1 = bar(curr,'FaceColor',rand(1,3));
    bh{k} = bar1;
    lh{k} = bar1(1);
end
hold off;

legend([lh{:}],{'1st group','2nd group', '3rd group', },...
    'fontweight','bold','Location','best','FontSize',12);
xlabel('Samples (45 Locations) ','fontweight','bold','FontSize',12);
ylabel('Distance Error (meters)','fontweight','bold','FontSize',12);
```

[image]

Thus, I need to do the following:

1. put specific numbers under each bar for each group along the x-axis
2. change the value "200" only at Y-axis into "NaN", while the remaining values not changed.

Comment: look at `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`

Comment: please, could you help using code example related to my case?

Comment: for 2 - type: `bar1(1).Parent.YTickLabel{end} = 'NaN';` at the end of your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XTickLabel with variable intervalls at barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507288/xticklabel-with-variable-intervalls-at-barplot)

Comment: Not working!!
i added this:  
set(gca,'xticklabel',[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45])
each bar group include 15 bar , i need to write 1-15 under 1st group bar, 15 - 30 under 2nd group bars , 30-45 under 3rd group bars, could any help?

Comment: Please, don't shout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative and more simple way to create this bar plot:

```
y = [200 200 200 192 160 128 96 64 48 32 96 64 24 48 32;
    6 6 2 4 4 6 12 8 2 4 8 6 16 12 6;
    48 64 96 48 32 24 24 64 16 24 48 32 48 64 24];
[rows,cols] = size(y);
col_id = reshape(1:cols*rows,[],rows); % generate number for the bars by group
w = 3; % amount of spacing between groups
col_pos = col_id+(0:rows-1)*w; % set the x-position for all bars
% if your Matlab version is <2016b, uncomment the folloing line instead of the line above:
% col_pos = bsxfun(@plus,col_id,(0:rows-1)*w);
hold on
for k = 1:rows
    bar(col_pos(:,k),y(k,:),'FaceColor',rand(1,3));
end
hold off
ax = gca;
ax.YTickLabel{end} = 'NaN'; % set the last y-tick to 'NaN'
ax.XTick = col_pos(:); % place x-ticks only under the bars
ax.XTickLabel = col_id(:); % set the x-ticks labels to the bar's id
xlim([0 col_pos(end)+1]) % remove extra space on the right
legend({'1st group','2nd group', '3rd group', },...
    'fontweight','bold','Location','best','FontSize',12);
xlabel('Samples (45 Locations) ','fontweight','bold','FontSize',12);
ylabel('Distance Error (meters)','fontweight','bold','FontSize',12);
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @MohsenAli can you write more specifically _what_ is not working?

Comment: Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in GPS_accuracy_plotting (line 50)
col_pos = col_id+(0:rows-1)*w; % set the x-position for all bars

Comment: This is just a backward compitabiliy issue. Replace this line with: `col_pos = bsxfun(@plus,col_id,(0:rows-1)*w);`.

Comment: yes it worked properly.

could you tell me how i can change font size of x, y values in our case?

Comment: You can write: `set(ax,'FontSize',12)` for a change in all text

Comment: i solved it using 
set(gca,'fontweight','bold','FontSize',12);
Thank you Dear

Comment: @MohsenAli since you already have a handle to the relevant axes (`ax`), it's better to use it then `gca`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163192/discussion-between-mohsen-ali-and-ebh).